# What is the difference between "sql-query" and "db-api"?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the difference between [sql-query](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-query) and [db-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db-api)?
Are there any cases where a question is about a SQL query, but it is not about the database API?
Should both the tags be kept, or should [db-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db-api) replace the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the questions for sql-query, the first clearly should be db-api, the second is a views question which is at least *not* db-api (not sure if it is sql-query) and the second clearly is a generic SQL question (although somewhat drupal specific), how the db api works doesn't really matter there.

So my suggestion would be to move the first question over to db-api but leave it on the other two.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is two different tags.
Example, if I am asking how to get taxonomy terms with node count by sql I tag question as **sql-query**. But if I shall ask how build pager query it will be **db-api** tag.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Xio; sql-query should be about "which query is needed to get my data from the db", while db-api is about "how do I build that query using the Drupal db layer", including all the fun stuff like hook_query_alter.

That said, one could argue that all sql-query questions are not Drupal-specific and should be asked on Stack Overflow.